# Matrix rotation

Tags: java, matrix

folks, I've been analyzing the following code about the rotation of matrix by 90 degrees:

```
static int[][] rotateCW(int[][] mat) {
    final int M = mat.length;
    final int N = mat[0].length;
    int[][] ret = new int[N][M];
    for (int r = 0; r < mat.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < mat[0].length; c++) {
            ret[c][mat.length-1-r] = mat[r][c];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The code works fine.
What I do not understand is why `c < mat[0].length` Shouldn't it be `c < mat[i].length` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be:

```
for (int r = 0; r < M; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
        ret[c][M-1-r] = mat[r][c]; 
        ...
```

Because using `M` and `N` is faster, saving indirection of storage access.

Also note that:

```
final int M = mat.length; // number of rows
final int N = mat[0].length; // number of columns
```

Because the number of columns in any row of any [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) is equal.

In the for loops `ret[c][mat.length-1-r]` or `ret[c][M-1-r]` is the *last-to-first* column for each row, where `mat[r][c]` is the is the *first-to-last* column for each row

Comment: what do `M` and `N` stand for exactly? @rakeb.void

Comment: Could you please expain the following line to me?:                                      `ret[c][mat.length-1-r] = mat[r][c];` @rakeb.void

Comment: @John, see the edited answer. Please try to debug for a smaller matrix (say 2*2 and initialize that with all different element) then everything will be clear to you.

Comment: when you said last-to-first so it means the first element position will be ret[0][1] ?? @rakeb.void

Comment: For a (2*2) matrix and for the first iteration, yes!

Comment: Note that using M and N is **faster**, saving indirections of storage access.

Comment: @JoopEggen, yes that's why I suggested to use M and N.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix has the same length for all rows (i.e. the same number of columns in each row), so if `mat` is a matrix, `mat[0].length` is equal to `mat[i].length` for any `i` from `0` to `mat.length-1`. Therefore it doesn't matter if you write `mat[i].length` or `mat[0].length`.

Comment: could you please explain this line to me?:                                    `ret[c][mat.length-1-r] = mat[r][c];`. I'm having hard time to understand it. @Eran

Comment: @John This line (and the loop it is part of) reverses each row of the input matrix and makes the reversed row a column in the output matrix. So {{1,2},{3,4}} will become {{2,4},{1,3}}

Answer (score 0):

They are checking the length of the matrix. Since the length is the same, the solution is correct. It certainly shouldn't be `c < mat[i].length` because `i` is not known in the scope, it should be (as it is) `c < mat[0].length` or better yet: `c < N`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mat[0].length representing the column length.
```

Comment: elebrate your answer so others can understand